# Renaming columns for PySpark DataFrame aggregates

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am analysing some data with PySpark DataFrames. Suppose I have a DataFrame `df` that I am aggregating:

```
(df.groupBy("group")
   .agg({"money":"sum"})
   .show(100)
)
```

This will give me:

```text
group                SUM(money#2L)
A                    137461285853
B                    172185566943
C                    271179590646
```

The aggregation works just fine but I dislike the new column name `SUM(money#2L)`. Is there a way to rename this column into something human readable from the `.agg` method? Maybe something more similar to what one would do in `dplyr`:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(sum_money = sum(money))
```

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Although I still prefer **dplyr** syntax, this code snippet will do:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

(df.groupBy("group")
   .agg(sf.sum('money').alias('money'))
   .show(100))
```

It gets verbose.

Comment: For anyone else that has copy-pasted this `alias` part but don't see it taking affect, pay attention to your parentheses. `alias('string')` exists **inside** the `agg`, otherwise you're aliasing the entire DataFrame not only the column.

Answer (score 89):

`withColumnRenamed` should do the trick. Here is the link to the [pyspark.sql API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=rename#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnRenamed).

```
df.groupBy("group")\
  .agg({"money":"sum"})\
  .withColumnRenamed("SUM(money)", "money")
  .show(100)
```

Comment: The `alias` is a good pointer, but this is the correct answer - there are good reasons to use the dictionary within `agg` at times and it seems the only way to "alias" an aggregated column is to rename it.

Comment: thank you! prefer `withColumnRenamed` over `alias`. Why? because `divide and conquer` works better than overloaded brain.

Answer (score 8):

I made a little helper function for this that might help some people out.

```py
import re

from functools import partial

def rename_cols(agg_df, ignore_first_n=1):
    """changes the default spark aggregate names `avg(colname)` 
    to something a bit more useful. Pass an aggregated dataframe
    and the number of aggregation columns to ignore.
    """
    delimiters = "(", ")"
    split_pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))
    splitter = partial(re.split, split_pattern)
    split_agg = lambda x: '_'.join(splitter(x))[0:-ignore_first_n]
    renamed = map(split_agg, agg_df.columns[ignore_first_n:])
    renamed = zip(agg_df.columns[ignore_first_n:], renamed)
    for old, new in renamed:
        agg_df = agg_df.withColumnRenamed(old, new)
    return agg_df
```

An example:

```py
gb = (df.selectExpr("id", "rank", "rate", "price", "clicks")
 .groupby("id")
 .agg({"rank": "mean",
       "*": "count",
       "rate": "mean", 
       "price": "mean", 
       "clicks": "mean", 
       })
)

>>> gb.columns
['id',
 'avg(rate)',
 'count(1)',
 'avg(price)',
 'avg(rank)',
 'avg(clicks)']

>>> rename_cols(gb).columns
['id',
 'avg_rate',
 'count_1',
 'avg_price',
 'avg_rank',
 'avg_clicks']
```

Doing at least a bit to save people from typing so much.

Comment: Very useful and timely. I was just about to ask the same question. It would be nice if you could specify a new column name within the `agg` dict (within Spark I mean).

Comment: @EvanZamir thanks! I might try and do a simple PR in spark for that.

Comment: You can simply rename by `df = df.toDF(*newColumnNames)`, whereby `newColumnNames` holds all column names of the DataFrame (df) :)

Comment: Hi, I made the following mod because with `ignore_first_n=2` it was truncating the last letter of the columns: `split_agg = lambda x: '_'.join(splitter(x))[:-1]`

Answer (score 7):

It's simple as:

```
 val maxVideoLenPerItemDf = requiredItemsFiltered.groupBy("itemId").agg(max("playBackDuration").as("customVideoLength"))
maxVideoLenPerItemDf.show()
```

Use `.as` in agg to name the new row created.

Comment: As of PySpark 2.4.0, the `.as('new_name')` should be `.alias('new_name')`.

Answer (score 6):

`.alias` and `.withColumnRenamed` both work if you're willing to hard-code your column names. If you need a programmatic solution, e.g. friendlier names for an aggregation of all remaining columns, this provides a good starting point:

```py
grouping_column = 'group'
cols = [F.sum(F.col(x)).alias(x) for x in df.columns if x != grouping_column]
(
    df
    .groupBy(grouping_column)
    .agg(
        *cols
    )
)
```

Comment: This piece of code is amazing! This is the way to do it. Should get more upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

```
df = df.groupby('Device_ID').agg(aggregate_methods)
for column in df.columns:
    start_index = column.find('(')
    end_index = column.find(')')
    if (start_index and end_index):
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column[start_index+1:end_index])
```

The above code can strip out anything that is outside of the "()". For example, "sum(foo)" will be renamed as "foo".

Comment: just watch out for columns without parentheses, they will be removed alltogether, such as the groupby var.  Can add a if/continue check. I had a single variable that was my groupby var, so just checked for that.

Answer (score 4):

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
data = [(1, "siva", 100), (2, "siva2", 200),(3, "siva3", 300),(4, "siva4", 400),(5, "siva5", 500)]
schema = ['id', 'name', 'sallary']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df.show()
+---+-----+-------+
| id| name|sallary|
+---+-----+-------+
|  1| siva|    100|
|  2|siva2|    200|
|  3|siva3|    300|
|  4|siva4|    400|
|  5|siva5|    500|
+---+-----+-------+


**df.agg({"sallary": "max"}).withColumnRenamed('max(sallary)', 'max').show()**
+---+
|max|
+---+
|500|
+---+
```

Answer (score 3):

While the previously given answers are good, I think they're lacking a neat way to deal with dictionary-usage in the `.agg()`

If you want to use a dict, which actually might be also dynamically generated because you have hundreds of columns, you can use the following without dealing with dozens of code-lines:

```py
# Your dictionary-version of using the .agg()-function
# Note: The provided logic could actually also be applied to a non-dictionary approach
df = df.groupBy("group")\
   .agg({
          "money":"sum"
        , "...":  "..."
    })

# Now do the renaming
newColumnNames = ["group", "money", "..."] # Provide the names for ALL columns of the new df
df = df.toDF(*newColumnNames)              # Do the renaming
```

Of course the `newColumnNames`-list can also be dynamically generated. E.g., if you only append columns from the aggregation to your `df` you can pre-store `newColumnNames = df.columns` and then just append the additional names.
Anyhow, be aware that the `newColumnNames` must contain all column names of the dataframe, not only those to be renamed (because `.toDF()` creates a new dataframe due to Sparks immutable RDDs)!

Answer (score 0):

Another quick little one liner to add the the mix:

```
df.groupBy('group')
  .agg({'money':'sum',
        'moreMoney':'sum',
        'evenMoreMoney':'sum'
        })
    .select(*(col(i).alias(i.replace("(",'_').replace(')','')) for i in df.columns))
```

just change the alias function to whatever you'd like to name them. The above generates sum_money, sum_moreMoney, since I do like seeing the operator in the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

**[Special case]**

If we want to rename the aggregated columns with the same name as the columns being summed over (i.e.: `sum(column1)` --> `column1`), we can do it like so:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

groupby_keys = ["categorical_column_1", "categorical_column_2"]
numerical_columns = ["numerical_column_1", "numerical_column_2"]

aggregation_computations = [F.sum(col).alias(col) for col in numerical_columns]
df = df.groupby(groupby_keys).agg(*aggregation_computations)
```

```
df.show()

+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| categorical_column_1 | categorical_column_2 | numerical_column_1 | numerical_column_2 |
+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|     category_1_1     |     category_2_1     |           1        |          1.0       |
|     category_1_2     |     category_2_1     |           2        |          2.0       |
|     category_1_1     |     category_2_2     |           3        |          3.0       |
|     category_1_2     |     category_2_2     |           4        |          4.0       |
+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is late to the party, but I think it's a more general solution than hardcoding a specific function and safer than trying to rename after the fact.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

y = {"money":"sum"}

df.groupBy("group").agg(
    *[ getattr(sf, fun)(col).alias(col) for col, fun in y.items() ]
)
```