# Pyspark 1.6 - Aliasing columns after pivoting with multiple aggregates

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pivot, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently trying to alias the columns I'm getting after pivoting on a value on a Pyspark dataframe. The problem here is that the columns names I'm putting in the alias call are not properly set.

A concrete example :

Starting from this dataframe :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

df = sc.parallelize([
    (217498, 100000001, 'A'), (217498, 100000025, 'A'), (217498, 100000124, 'A'),
    (217498, 100000152, 'B'), (217498, 100000165, 'C'), (217498, 100000177, 'C'),
    (217498, 100000182, 'A'), (217498, 100000197, 'B'), (217498, 100000210, 'B'),
    (854123, 100000005, 'A'), (854123, 100000007, 'A')
]).toDF(["user_id", "timestamp", "actions"])
```

which gives

```
+-------+--------------------+------------+
|user_id|     timestamp      |  actions   |
+-------+--------------------+------------+
| 217498|           100000001|    'A'     |
| 217498|           100000025|    'A'     |
| 217498|           100000124|    'A'     |
| 217498|           100000152|    'B'     |
| 217498|           100000165|    'C'     |
| 217498|           100000177|    'C'     |
| 217498|           100000182|    'A'     |
| 217498|           100000197|    'B'     |
| 217498|           100000210|    'B'     |
| 854123|           100000005|    'A'     |
| 854123|           100000007|    'A'     |
```

The problem is that calling

```
df = df.groupby('user_id')\
       .pivot('actions')\
       .agg(func.count('timestamp').alias('ts_count'),
            func.mean('timestamp').alias('ts_mean'))
```

gives the columns names

```
df.columns

['user_id',
 'A_(count(timestamp),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false) AS ts_count#4L',
 'A_(avg(timestamp),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false) AS ts_mean#5',
 'B_(count(timestamp),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false) AS ts_count#4L',
 'B_(avg(timestamp),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false) AS ts_mean#5',
 'C_(count(timestamp),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false) AS ts_count#4L',
 'C_(avg(timestamp),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false) AS ts_mean#5']
```

which are completely impractical.

I could clean my column names with the methods shown [here - (regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836877/rename-pivoted-and-aggregated-column-in-pyspark-dataframe)
or [here - (use of withColumnRenamed()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988287/renaming-columns-for-pyspark-dataframes-aggregates).
However these are workarounds that could easily break after an update.

To sum it up: How can I use the columns generated by the pivot without having to parse them ? (e.g. 'A_(count(timestamp),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false) AS ts_count#4L' generated name) ?

Any help would be appreciated !
Thanks

Comment: Naming scheme has been modified in 2.0 but what is the question here?

Comment: I think that OP's question is : How can he use the columns generated by the pivot without having to parse the 'A_(count(timestamp),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false) AS ts_count#4L' generated name ?

Comment: Yes that's it ! thanks @devict

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the column you are pivoting on doesn't have distinct values. This results in duplicate column names when the pivot occurs so spark gives it those column names to make them distinct. You need to group your pivot column before you pivot to make the values in the pivot column (actions) distinct.

Let me know if you need more help!

@hyperc54