# Pyspark Column name alias when applying Aggregate using a Dictionary

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am applying an aggregate function on a data frame in pyspark. I am using a dictionary to pass the column name and aggregate function

`df.groupBy(column_name).agg({"column_name":"sum"})`

I now want to apply an alias to this column that has been generated using the aggregate method. Is there a way to do it?

The reason I am using the dictionary method is that aggregates will be applied dynamically depending on input parameters.

So basically it will be like

```
def aggregate(df, column_to_group_by, columns_to_aggregate):
     df.groupBy(column_to_group_by).agg(columns_to_aggregate)
```

Where `columns_to_aggregate` will look like

```
{
   "salary":"sum"
}
```

I now want to apply alias to the newly created column, because If I try to save the result to disk as praquet I get the error

```
Column name "sum(salary)" contains invalid character(s). Please use alias to rename it.
```

Any help on how to apply alias dynamically will be great

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum
df.groupBy("state") \
  .agg(sum("salary").alias("sum_salary"))
```

Please read the [article](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-column-alias-after-groupby/)

Comment: That does not answer my question, I clearly stated I want to use the dictionary format for aggregation, {"column_name" :"agg_function"} to make my method dynamic.

Comment: in such case easiest way is to use spark sql : just create nesessary string and execute it. Example : val results = spark.sql("Your generated string"). Same thing like in Oracle with dynamic sql. Use your functions to build the query

Answer (score 0):

I can see that this question is from 4 months ago. Here is the link to a possible solution where you rename the columns after aggregation by replacing some characters:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70101696

The provided solution:

```
df.groupBy('group')
  .agg({'money':'sum',
        'moreMoney':'sum',
        'evenMoreMoney':'sum'
        })
    .select(*(col(i).alias(i.replace("(",'_').replace(')','')) for i in df.columns))
```

It will create columns: sum_money, sume_moreMoney etc. And of course you can choose to rename/replace differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spark's `withColumnRenamed` method in addition to your data frame aggregation. Say, you are grouping by `department`

```
df.groupBy("department").agg({"salary":"sum"}).withColumnRenamed("sum(salary)", "sum" )
```

Hope this will answer your question.